# How to correctly configure ServerSocketReceiver with Logback

Tags: java, logging, logback

I want to receive logs from client applications on a server.
I have tried the standard 'receiver' configuration provided in the logback-examples project.

```
<configuration debug="true">

  <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
  </root>

  <receiver class="ch.qos.logback.classic.net.server.ServerSocketReceiver">
    <port>6000</port>
  </receiver>

</configuration>
```

When logback parses this file it gives the following error:

```
16:28:09,067 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@19:76 - no applicable action for [receiver], current pattern is [[configuration][receiver]]
16:28:09,068 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@20:11 - no applicable action for [port], current pattern is [[configuration][receiver][port]]
```

I am at a loss as to what is wrong with the configuration.
I have: slf4j-api-1.7.5, logback-classic-1.0.9, logback-core-1.0.9

Unsurprisingly the client logging fails to send to the server:

```
16:30:39,052 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SocketAppender[SERVER] - Could not connect to remote logback server at [MAGENTA.comrad.local]. We will try again later. java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
```

Comment: Is this particular server doing just this one task? i.e. receiving messages and logging them? If so, are you running SimpleSocketServer? If so, you would not need to define a Receiver.

Comment: I have managed to get SimpleSocketServer working. However I don't want a separate standalone program. I would prefer to do the logging using the existing server application. Hence the need to configure it as a receiver in logback.xml. (Assuming I have understood the manual correctly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that I got the error was that I was linking to logback 1.0.9.
The receiver functionality is only in 1.012 and newer.